# Managed Publishing in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, publishing

I have set up my app store listing and uploaded two versions in the **Internal test track** and everything got reviewed. I want to move my app to production at a specified time. For this, I have found **Managed Publishing**. It is recommended to upload the app to **Closed Test Track in Google Play Console** if we want to manage our app's publishing. So, I have enabled the **Managed Publishing** for the app and promote my release from **Internal Test Track to Closed Test Track**. The version is **Ready to Publish in Closed Test Track**. Since, I want to avoid delay in my app launch due to review process, I tried to promote the release from **Closed Test Track to Production**. I have saved the details and done Review Release, now the console display the **Start Roll out to Production** button. If I give **Start Roll out to Production**, will the app be published immediately in Play Store or wait in **Managed Publishing** section. In the documentation, they have said "***Your app must already be available to use managed publishing. You can’t use it when publishing an app for the first time.***" It leads to my confusion. I have also planned to enable **pre-registration** for my app. So, if my app get published immediately, it will affect my plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I did a test. If you turned on **Managed Publishing** the production will not be be published immediately. It will wait on **Managed Publishing** until we manually release.